# subroutine not working when run as a sheet macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a process that created a .xlsm file with a sheet macro, ie a macro that is internal to the sheet and not run in a separate module.

Inside one of the sheet subroutines, I am trying to import a .csv file using this method:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & INFILE, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "NLIST"
    .FieldNames = True
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(8, 36, 2, 4, 7, 4, 4)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

The issue is that is **doesn't** work as a sheet macro.
**It only works when it's inside it's own module.**
I have tried changing all the "." references to this sort of structure:

```
With sheets("NLIST").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & INFILE, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    sheets("NLIST").Name = "NLIST"
    sheets("NLIST").FieldNames = True
End with
```

no buenos

As always, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Edit1:** Since it doesn't work, try creating the procedure in a module level and call it in your sheet code.

For example: *This goes in a Module*

```
Sub AddConnection(targetWS As Worksheet, INFILE As String)

With targetWS
    With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & INFILE, Destination:=.Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "NLIST"
        .FieldNames = True
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(8, 36, 2, 4, 7, 4, 4)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

And then in your sheet code, you can call it like:

```
AddConnection Me, <FilePath> '/* if you are creating connection in that sheet */
```

or

```
AddConnection Sheets("NLIST"), <FilePath> '/* creating it on another sheet */
```

Not tested, no way to do it atm, but I think it should work.

Comment: Nope. sorry, I tried that and got the same result. Sheet macros interacting with other sheets in the same workbook is always a bit odd.

Comment: I set up the code as you suggested, ( using a separate module ). What happens now, is that when the "With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:=" line in the Module runs, the code immediately jumps back to the next line in the Sheet macro.

Comment: @AnthonyBouttell What do you mean by *jumps back to the next line*?

Comment: sorry,
I single stepped through the process:
When I ran "AddConnection Me, Infile", in the Sheet macro,
control was transferred to the Module macro, "Sub AddConnection(targetWS As Worksheet, INFILE As String) 
the cursor went to the first statement "With targetWS"
but when the next line, "with .Querytablea.Add(Connection:= ...... 
should have been executed, control jumped back to the Sheet macro, and the line following "AddConnection Me, Infile"
was executed.
Does that make sence?

Comment: <rant> As an aside, adding  comments to clarify points is way flawed. Nothing can be formatted to make it clear what is being said. And extra code code is illegible.  if new code is added  using the existing system, it is then out of sequence with the comments.... </rant>

Comment: @AnthonyBouttell That is the correct behavior when you use `AddConnection Me, InFile` cause that will execute the code on the sheet where the sheet module is. How about executing the second example. It should run the code at `Sheet("NLIST')`.